# PowerShell Selenium WebDriver and ChromeDriver - FindElementBy() syntax differences

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've followed the steps in this article https://adamtheautomator.com/selenium-powershell/ and a couple of others, to install Selenium WebDriver and ChromeDriver for use with PowerShell. Things are fine, however, I did struggle to implement the use of `FindElementByXPath()` or `FindElementByCssSelector()`. It didn't find a master documentation for using Selenium WebDriver and ChromeDriver form PowerShell. It seems there is some issue with the methods `FindElementXXXXX()` as they are not working in my case, although they are mentioned in the above-mentioned article.

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to implement `FindElementBy()` as follows:

```
$scriptPath = "C:\Projects\Selenium\Setup"
Add-Type -path "$scriptPath\webdriver.dll"

$ChromeOptions = $null
#$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
#$ChromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user_dir\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\")

$chrome = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)
#$chrome = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver
$usernameVal = "user-name"
$pwordVal = "password432"
$chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://your-website-with-username-pwd.com")

Start-Sleep -s 6

$loginName = [OpenQA.Selenium.By]::CssSelector("#loginName-id")
$loginNameElm = $chrome.FindElement($loginName)
$loginNameElm.SendKeys($usernameVal)

$pword = [OpenQA.Selenium.By]::CssSelector("[a-id=password-input-xyz]")
$pwordElm = $chrome.FindElement($pword)
$pwordElm.SendKeys($pwordVal)

$btnLogin = [OpenQA.Selenium.By]::CssSelector("#ng-app > div.app.ng-scope > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > form > div > div.ng-isolate-scope > div > div > div > div > div.fis-action-bar.clearfix.ng-scope > div.fis-block > div.fis-primary-block > button")
#The CSS Selector below didn't work
#$btnLogin = [OpenQA.Selenium.By]::CssSelector("button:contains('Sign in')")
$btnLoginElm = $chrome.FindElement($btnLogin)
$btnLoginElm.click()
```

So as you can see the trick is to use the syntax `[OpenQA.Selenium.By]` namespace or class.

What really puzzled me is in all references to this form are using the syntax `By.CssSelector()` as in this page https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/find-element-selenium/.

Also, I tried to use CSS Selector format `button:contains('Sign in')` but it did throw an error although it is working using `$()` notation. If I used the other normal selector (by copying it from Chrome DevTools) it works fine. I was trying to avoid having a supper long css selector that looks funny.

So the question is:

- Where is the main documentation for using Selenium from PowerShell?
- Why there are different variations if the use of a method like `FindElementBy` and in other instance we see `FindElementByXPath()`?
- How we can import the namespace[OpenQA.Selenium.By] to avoid typing the whole name? So that we use the syntax `By.CssSelector()` directly in PowerShell.
- How can we locate a button with the value used for the caption? That is to avoid using a very long CSS Selector.
- I don't like the option to use sleep in PowerShell to wait until Chrome is ready. Is there another better way?